# Запрос по нескольким таблицам без связи в Access

Tags: ms-access, связи

Нужно определить вхождения даты в неделю. Для этого создал отдельную таблицу с номерами (названиями, они текстовые типа 2017-w-1) недель.

Таблица Week: name, home_data, end_data.

Я создаю запрос, на основание главной таблицы Result, в которой есть поле [Дата_завершения], на основание его, я создаю вычисляемое поле с условием - Неделя: IIf([Дата_завершения] Between [Week]![Home_data] And [Week]![End_data];[Week]![name];'За пределами диапазона ').

И как результат, у меня вместо 1000 записей получается 54 000, так как в таблице Week 54 записи. Получается, что одно вычисление правильное, а 53 'За пределами диапазона'.

Как установить связь, или как работать без связи? Мне потом нужна будет группировка по неделям...

Answer (score 0):

К радости сам и нашел ответ на свой вопрос, вернее подсказали на другом ресурсе:

**Неделя: DatePart("ww";[Дата_завершения];2;2)**

И все, не надо изобретать велосипедов, создавать лишние таблицы. Почему нигде не нашел этого, не понимаю, везде слишком запутанные решения.